# AND, OR output wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, operators, operator-precedence

Suppose I use 2 `AND` and one `OR` to retrieve a result, first test with input text value on `name`, I could get correct result but when I change `$getc` to any value other than empty string, the result does not change, it only query `name` value. What is wrong?

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE name LIKE '%$asd%' OR descriptions LIKE
    '%$asd%' AND category='$getc' AND company_type='$dsp' LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Answer (score 8):

Try putting `()` around `name LIKE '%$asd%' OR descriptions LIKE '%$asd%'` as:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE (name LIKE '%$asd%' OR descriptions LIKE '%$asd%') AND category='$getc' AND company_type='$dsp' LIMIT $start, $limit";
```

Which says `category` and `company_type` ***must*** match and ***at least one*** of `name` and `descriptions` must match.

Reason:

```
a OR b AND c AND d
```

is treated as following as `AND` is having higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`

```
a OR (b AND c AND d)
```

but what you want is:

```
(a OR b) AND c AND d
```

Comment: It was strange that I still get no result after putting a bracket before I post this question.

Comment: Ok, I manage to get it right use !empty() to validate each parameter and add them into mysql statement if there a value.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but I didn't have an account. I experienced in mysql, some time too much code make my brain go haywire.